# How do I capture the output of the Java console in a file when debugging a failed SSL handshake?

Tags: java, ssl

I want to debug `java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly` by viewing the Java debug output. I can't see the Java console when running my application, so I want to store the SSL debug logs in a file:

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "client_truststore.ks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "myPass");
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake");
        
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("./ssl.txt"));
        System.setOut(out);

        URL url = new URL("https://myURL:8080/myService?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName("http://mynamespace.com", "MyImplService");
        MyServiceagent service = new MyServiceagent(url, qname);
        MyPort port = service.getMyPortPort();
```

However, nothing is written to ssl.txt. Where is the output going and why isn't it writing to the file?

EDIT:I switched to absolute file paths and can see that the files are being created, but still have no content. `javax.net.debug` isn't going to either the out or error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set these system properties before initializing the **server,** instead of doing so after creating the server but before the client.

Answer (score 0):

The error output is likely on the error stream and not the out stream. You could try

```
System.setErr(out);
```

Comment: I redirected both the error and out streams to two different files; neither is being written to.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach i would suggest to try writing it through file output stream or try serializing.. like if you are expecting any exception, put that under try block. Then in catch block get the exception message and then write it to a file. (File Output stream).. in case you are not aware about file output stream , serialization please google it once.

Also, normally all enterprise has certain configurations to capture the logs. Like log.error to capture the error logs . Similarly you can update the configurations to debug level to capture the debug logs like log.debug

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the redirect while invoking your JVM :
java -Djavax.net.debug=all -jar  >> output.log 2>&1